# React JS - useeffect in function is calling twice

Tags: reactjs

im very confused now.
Im trying to implement code that will get some data from iframe.
Everything works correct but the function is calling always twice.

I mean inside the useeffect.

The code is working perfectly but only one thing is driving me crazy because I don't understand why this is happening and I can't fix it - can anyone help?
I am pasting the code.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
import BarChart from '../charts/BarChart01';
import {
  Box,
  Button,
  Dialog,
  DialogActions,
  DialogContent,
  DialogTitle,
  IconButton,
  MenuItem,
  Stack,
  TextField,
  Select,
  Tooltip,
  InputLabel,
  Switch,
  FormControlLabel,
  darken,
} from '@mui/material';
import liveIconAnimated from "../images/liveAnimatedIcon.json";
import liveIconAnimated2 from "../images/liveAnimatedIcon2.json";
import Lottie from "lottie-react";


// Import utilities
import { tailwindConfig } from '../utils/Utils';
import axios from 'axios';
//import getFacebookCommants from '../FacebookExtension/getFacebookCommants';

const LiveCard01 = () => {
    //getFacebookCommants({password: false, roomID: 'RizqN7AYrs'});

  const [socialStreamPassword, setSocialStreamPassword] = useState(false);
  const [socialStreamRoomId, setSocialStreamRoomId] = useState('');
  const [socialStreamIsTrue, setSocialStreamIsTrue] = useState(false);
  
  const Comment = ({ avatar, comment, username, provider }) => (
    <div className="flex items-center mb-4 px-4 py-4 bg-slate-200">
      <div className="w-12 h-12 py-2 rounded-full overflow-visible object-none">
        <img className="scale-150 rounded-full" src={avatar} alt="Avatar" />
      </div>
      <div className="ml-4">
        <div className="font-bold text-gray-900">{username}</div>
        <span className='text-m ml-2 font-sans text-gray-800'>{comment}</span>
        <div className="text-sm ml-2 text-gray-500">- {provider}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );

  const [comments, setComments] = useState([]);
  const [loadedComments, setLoadedComments] = useState(10);
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);

  const loadMoreComments = () => {
    setLoadedComments(prevLoadedComments => prevLoadedComments + 5);
  };

  const rewindComments = () => {
    setLoadedComments(10);
  };
  const toggleExpand = () => {
    setExpanded(prevExpanded => !prevExpanded);
    if (!expanded) {
      setLoadedComments(comments.length);
    } else {
      setLoadedComments(10);
    }
  };
  const removeImgTags = (text) => {
    const regex = /<img\b[^>]*>/g;
    return text.replace(regex, "");
  };


  function getFacebookCommants({ password, roomID, socialstreamopen }) {
    const iframeRef = useRef(null);
    const previousParamsRef = useRef({ password: '', roomID: '' });
    const [commentIds, setCommentIds] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
      if (previousParamsRef.current.password === password && previousParamsRef.current.roomID === roomID) {
        return;
      }
    
      const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
      iframe.src = `https://vdo.socialstream.ninja/?ln&salt=vdo.ninja&password=${password}&push&label=dock&vd=0&ad=0&novideo&noaudio&autostart&cleanoutput&room=${roomID}`;
      iframe.style.width = "0px";
      iframe.style.height = "0px";
      iframe.style.position = "fixed";
      iframe.style.left = "-100px";
      iframe.style.top = "-100px";
      iframe.id = "frame1";
      iframe.setAttribute("crossorigin", "anonymous");
      iframeRef.current = iframe;
    
      console.log(iframe.src)
    
      if (iframeRef.current && iframeRef.current instanceof Node) {
        document.body.appendChild(iframeRef.current);
      }
    
      const eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
      const eventer = window[eventMethod];
      const messageEvent = eventMethod === "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";
    
      const handleMessage = (e) => {
        if (e.source !== iframeRef.current.contentWindow) {
          return; // reject messages sent from other iframes
        }
        if ("dataReceived" in e.data) { // raw data
          if ("overlayNinja" in e.data.dataReceived) {
            console.log(e.data.dataReceived.overlayNinja);
            const newComment = {
              id: comments.length + 1,
              username: e.data.dataReceived.overlayNinja.chatname,
              avatar: e.data.dataReceived.overlayNinja.chatimg,
              comment: removeImgTags(e.data.dataReceived.overlayNinja.chatmessage),
              provider: e.data.dataReceived.overlayNinja.type,
            };
    
            if (!commentIds.includes(newComment.id)) {
              setComments((prevComments) => [newComment, ...prevComments]);
              setCommentIds((prevIds) => [...prevIds, newComment.id]);
              if (expanded) {
                setLoadedComments((prevLoadedComments) => prevLoadedComments + 1);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      };
    
      eventer(messageEvent, handleMessage);
    
      previousParamsRef.current = { password, roomID };
    
      return () => {
        if (iframeRef.current && iframeRef.current instanceof Node) {
          document.body.removeChild(iframeRef.current);
        }
        eventer(messageEvent, handleMessage);
      };
    }, [password, roomID]);
  
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Iframe will be added dynamically.</p>
      </div>
    );
  }

  getFacebookCommants({password: socialStreamPassword, roomID: socialStreamRoomId, socialstreamopen: socialStreamIsTrue})

  return (
    <>
    <div className="flex flex-col col-span-full sm:col-span-6 bg-white shadow-lg rounded-sm border border-slate-200">
      <header className="px-5 py-4 border-b border-slate-100">
        <h2 className="font-semibold text-slate-800">Aktualna transmisja LIVE</h2>
        <h4 className="text-slate-800 font-thin">Status: 
            {socialStreamIsTrue? 
            <span className='text-green-800 font-bold'> ON</span>
            : <span className='text-red-800 font-bold'> OFF</span>
            }
        </h4>

        <div className='flex grow-0 h-10 grid-flow-col gap-4 my-2'>
        <Button
              color="error"
              size="small"
              startIcon={<div className="shrink-0 h-7 w-7" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><Lottie animationData={liveIconAnimated2}/></div>}
              onClick={() => {setSocialStreamIsTrue(true), setSocialStreamRoomId('eLEK9Wh47N')}}
              //onClick={() => getFacebookCommants('/593765932843411/live_comments','EAAHOlalTkn0BALnIthxp8eICQ0hykl4GDGJ93Ndb1x3viV9EtO4toUazsf3mH9MsBjkapselv8V9ZBeOJO5ZCcZCe35Cr3vUgxgyDpYEAV4JJfHyVZCE34K6NbAzszoEDGfx98dRmOsbfgoI1699vzXIuKI784MzYNx7QhRASs6iuZCAipX2LWQxysZBqhhusZD%22')}
              variant="outlined"
            >
              Dodaj aktywną transmisje
            </Button>
        </div>

      </header>
      {/* Chart built with Chart.js 3 */}
      {/* Change the height attribute to adjust the chart height */}
      <div className="grid gap-4 grid-cols-2">
      <div className="container mx-auto py-8 px-8">
      <h1 className="text-m font-bold mb-4">Wszystkie komentarze</h1>
      <div className="space-y-4 overflow-y-auto h-96">
        {comments.slice(0, expanded ? comments.length : loadedComments).map(comment => (
          <Comment key={comment.id} avatar={comment.avatar} comment={comment.comment} username={comment.username} provider={comment.provider}/>
        ))}
      </div>
      {comments.length > loadedComments && (
        <div className="mt-4">
          <button
            className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-600 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"
            onClick={toggleExpand}
          >
            {expanded ? 'Zwiń listę komentarzy' : 'Pokaż więcej komentarzy'}
          </button>
        </div>
      )}
      {expanded && loadedComments < comments.length && (
        <div className="mt-4">
          <button
            className="bg-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-600 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"
            onClick={loadMoreComments}
          >
            Pokaż więcej
          </button>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
    <div className="container mx-auto py-8 px-8">
      <h1 className="text-m font-bold mb-4">komentarze zawierające klucz</h1>
      <div className="space-y-4 overflow-y-auto h-96">
      {comments
        .filter(comment => comment.comment.includes("8") || comment.comment.includes("Stare") || comment.comment.includes("testowe"))
        .slice(0, expanded ? comments.length : loadedComments)
        .map(comment => (
          <Comment key={comment.id} avatar={comment.avatar} comment={comment.comment} username={comment.username} provider={comment.provider}/>
        ))}
      </div>
      {comments.length > loadedComments && (
        <div className="mt-4">
          <button
            className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-600 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"
            onClick={toggleExpand}
          >
            {expanded ? 'Zwiń listę komentarzy' : 'Pokaż więcej komentarzy'}
          </button>
        </div>
      )}
      {expanded && loadedComments < comments.length && (
        <div className="mt-4">
          <button
            className="bg-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-600 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"
            onClick={loadMoreComments}
          >
            Pokaż więcej
          </button>
        </div>
      )}
      </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default LiveCard01;
```

We are talking about the `function getFacebookCommants()` function, or maybe im not true.
Please help :)
i cant figure out the solution, ive spent like 20h for now :/

Comment: This can be caused by StrictMode. Can you check if your root component (mostly App.js) is inside `<React.StrictMode>`. If so remove it and check if it causes extra render.

Comment: You are calling `getFacebookCommants` in the component's body. It will be called every time any state changes

Comment: @SuleymanSah i forgot to notice that - i've <React.StrictMode> off :) 
Other things work correctly, just this one case.

Comment: @Konrad I know it, but i dont know how to change it :D
When im trying to use this function in return it just giving some errors.

Comment: `useEffect(() => getFacebookCommants(...), [])`?

Comment: @Konrad I've tried, there is the error:

`react-dom.development.js:16227 Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)`

Comment: You placed your `useEffect` in the wrong place I guess

Comment: @Konrad I think the same but i cannot figure out the mistake...

Answer (score 0):

Okay i figure it out.

The problem was in the useeffect.
Im calling setCommands in the useEffect enter, i move this code to the
return () => {} so it's simply calling on useeffect exit, and thats it.

Its work.